# Django: how to properly handle a database connection error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a desktop application that send POST requests to a server where a django app store the results. DB server and web server are not on the same machine and it happens that sometimes the connectivity is lost for a very short time but results in a connection error on some requests:

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (110)")

On a "normal" website I guess you'd not worry too much: the browser display a 500 error page and the visitor tries again later. 
In my case loosing info posted by a request is not an option and I am wondering how to handle this? I'd try to catch on this exception, wait for the connectivity to come back (lag is not a problem) and then continue the process. But as the exception can occur about anywhere in the code I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Is the desktop application also a Django app? If not, why is this question tagged python/mysql/django? Please elaborate on the client-side stack.

Comment: No the desktop app is built with native code (C++) and is already deployed, nothing can be done on that side anymore (it would have been a better solution for sure). Isn't it possible to do something on the server now?

Comment: OK, you're talking about web server <-> DB connection, not desktop <-> web server connection. Got it.

Comment: Yes, the problem is the connection between the web server and the database server. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could make [your own WSGI application](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_application_interface) that would decorate django's wsgi application, in yourproject/wsgi.py.

If your wsgi application decorator doesn't get an acceptable from the decorated application, it could wait a while and try again later.

But in reality, you should fix the client. The client should not expect to be connected to a working server 24/7. Until then I wouldn't thrust this desktop client as a user.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a middleware with a process_view method and a try / except wrapping your call.

Or you could decorate your views and wrap the call there.

Or you could use class based views with a base class that has a method decorator on its dispatch method, or an overriden.dispatch.

Really, you have plenty of solutions.

Now, as said above, you might want to modify your Desktop application too!